# How to manage collaborative comments in TFS 2017

Tags: tfs, changeset, comments

In Team Foundation Server (TFS) 2017 commenting on changesets is enhanced with additional functionality supporting markdown, "@ Mentions" that notify a person they were mentioned, and so on. There is also a nice drop down with status such as "pending", "won't fix" etc.

I've not found any documentation indicating how to leverage this, such as a list of "pending" comments, "won't fix" etc.

I'm utilizing TFS 2017 Update 2 on premise. 
Any ideas on how to organize, review, and manage this? These seem completely separate from the "Request Code Review" functionality.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Code Review function requires Team Explorer/Visual Studio, it's a client based feature.

Adding comments on web portal is web based feature. You can only see them on web portal.

Regarding the status of comments on web portal, there are five status: **Active**, **Pending**, **Resolved**, **Won't fix**, and **Closed**. When you add a new comment, the status is Active. You could change the status to Pending when you work on this comment, if the issue/query in the comment is resolved, change the status to Resolved, otherwise, change it to Won't fix. After verifying the changes, you could change the status to Closed.

Comment: I understand the difference between code review and the web annotations. However is there any way to list or track the web annotations?  For example if I make a comment and put it as pending how can I find that in the future?

Comment: Currently, you could check the comments on the right panel on changeset site.

Comment: I found the location in the database and am just scraping them manually. I'd like to know if there is any table that stores the selected text coordinates or something like that to show what specific code section the code comment was related to.

for instance, I can get the code discussion, but if I highlight a section of code in the changeset and comment on it, I haven't found anything that helps relate the selected text to the comment. Thus for me to currently scrap it I have to paste in the code in question into a markdown code snippet within the comment itself which is extra duplication